# In a SELECT, take one group of fields or another depending on a field value

Tags: sql-server

What is wrong with the commented out part in the SELECT below ?
If I uncomment the whole CASE...END, the SELECT becomes invalid.
What I want is, depending on wether there is a delivery address or not, take one group of address fields or another, ideally WITHOUT repeating the condition or using a COALESCE for each field. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.
Thanks !

```
  SELECT a, b, c,
  --        CASE x is null 
  --            THEN d, e, f,
  --            ELSE g, h, i,
  --        END
        k, l, m
  FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 2):

consider to put the condition for x in the where clause and then union

```
select a,b,c,d,e,f from table where x is null
union
select a,b,c,g,h,i from table where x is not null
```

the case thing needs a WHEN. I always use this structure

```
CASE ...
WHEN ...
THEN ...
ELSE ...
END AS Fieldname
```

all 5 must be present. it can be used to define one ouputfield. within it you could of course coallesce, but it will not give back an array of fields

EDIT: the ELSE is in fact not necessary, read informed comment below

Comment: `CASE` expressions (they are not "things") do not require an `ELSE` part.

Comment: Better to use `UNION ALL` for efficiency. And to be precise. The `UNION` will eliminate any duplicates.

Comment: ok, didn't know that the ELSE part is optional, thanks. And here is my knowledge drill: expression expression expression expression expression

Comment: right: the UNION without the ALL unifies distinctly, thanks for the reminder. that can be costly indeed...

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you the right answer and it's also easy to modify

```
select
    s.a, s.b, s.c,
    a.f1, a.f2, a.f3,
    s.k, s.l, s.m
from sometable as s
    outer apply (
        select s.d as f1, s.e as f2, s.f as f3 where s.x is null
        union all
        select s.g as f1, s.h as f2, s.i as f3 where s.x is not null
    ) as a
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e535/2)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `WHEN`, and you're only allowed to return a single value from a `CASE` *expression*:

```
SELECT a, b, c,
      CASE WHEN x is null 
          THEN d
          ELSE g
      END,
      CASE WHEN x is null 
          THEN e
          ELSE h
      END,
      CASE WHEN x is null 
          THEN  f
          ELSE i
      END,
    k, l, m
FROM sometable
```

This also assumes the types of `d` and `g` are compatible, as are (`e`,`h`) and (`f`,`i`)

Comment: I wonder why this got a downvote. It's a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: @ypercube - probably someone was annoyed that I didn't achieve " ideally WITHOUT repeating ..."

Comment: I guessed so, too. But your answer is also the only one that explains clearly why the OP's query doesn't work.